# SQL IN statement in Linq for NHibernate

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I have this Lookup to group ResultId by Symbol.
I have Linq query below but I cannot make SQL IN statement by using Contain() which is state by this post http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql

```
        // This will group ResultIds (Guid) by their symbol (string).
        var asd = ResultIdsAndSymbols.ToLookup(x => x.Symbol, y => y.ResultID);

        foreach (var qwe in asd)
        {
            var Numbers = (from t in Session.Query<TableName>()
                         where qwe.Contains(t.ResultID)
                         select t.Number).ToList();
        }
```

**Update:**

After retrying this code and deep analyzing the error (System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible), I got this informative error message: *"Failed to convert parameter value from a Grouping to a Guid"*. `qwe` is a type of `IGrouping<string, Guid>` and it will become `IEnumerable<Guid>` which should not be a problem like we pass this into a `List` constructor or used in `foreach` statement. The exception thrown in `System.Data.SqlClient`. I think NHibernate simply pass the `Grouping<TKey, TElement>` into the sql parameter that cause the error. NHibernate should be designed to enumerate to any `IEnumerable<T>` and generate the SQL IN query just like how it does for `List<T>`.

The `List<T>`, Array[], `Stack` work well. So I change the code to this:

```
where qwe.ToList().Contains(t.ResultID)
```

**Update:**
Issue reported: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2762

Comment: The issue report link you provided doesn't work.

Comment: Probably they move to Jira cloud. I update the link but it not a popular bug and they simply put Unresolved. However @Aaronaught said it fixed on v3.2 below.

Comment: The link works OK now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The NHibernate LINQ provider is limited when it comes to the IN clause. It seems to only work with collections where T is a simple type, e.g. `List<string>` or `List<int>`.

This works in NHibernate 3.1 (not tested in earlier versions):

```
var asd = ResultIdsAndSymbols.ToLookup(x => x.Symbol, y => y.ResultID);

foreach (var qwe in asd)
{
    List<int> list = qwe.ToList();
    var Numbers = (from t in Session.Query<TableName>()
                 where list.Contains(t.ResultID)
                 select t.Number).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I tried using simple array or generic List. What I remember it throw something like SQL query empty or not available (sql query never generated). I use nhibernate 3.1 also! Why you can.

Comment: @CallMeLaNN Could you post the code and the exact error you get? I'm willing to help resolve this but I need to be able to reproduce the error for that.

Comment: It takes a while to get in touch with the code in a branch. However I cannot reproduce the error. Now retrying the code only happened for `Lookup` type. for the other list, collection or array got no problem. Thanks.

Comment: It should not work only for collections but any type that implement `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Same problem (and solution) exists in NHibernate 3.2.